# Flip Card not working properly [can select text that is on the other side]

Tags: css, sass

My issue is that I can select the text on the front of the card even when the card is flipped and the only thing being shown is the back of the card. I do not understand why is that happening.

Here's a gif demonstrating the issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShqJq.jpg

Thank you for taking the time to help me!

HTML for one card:

```
<div class="pricing-container">
        <!-- Card 1 -->
        <div class="pricing-container__card-container">
            <div class="card-1 cards">
                <figure class="card-1__front">
                    <div class="card-1__front-top">
                        <h1 class="card-headers">Pack 1</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-1__front-bottom">
                        <ul class="card-1__front-bottom-list">
                            <li class="list-items">lorem</li>
                            <li class="list-items">lorem</li>
                            <li class="list-items">lorem</li>
                            <li class="list-items">lorem</li>
                            <li class="list-items">lorem</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </figure>
                <figure class="card-1__back">
                    <h1>PRICE: $20</h1>
                    <button class="pricing-container__btn">BUY</button>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.pricing-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: var(--color-primary);
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    
    &__card-container{
        width: 45rem;
        height: 65rem;
        
        &:hover .cards{
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            
        }
    }
    
    &__btn{
        margin-top: 3rem;
        border: none;
        width: 20rem;
        height: 7rem;
        border-radius: 50px;
        
        font-size: 2.7rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, var(--color-card-btn-gradient-1), var(--color-card-btn-gradient-2));
        color: #fff;
        
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8rem;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

.cards{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card-1, .card-2, .card-3{
    overflow-x: visible;
    position: relative;

    
    &__front{
        background: var(--color-secondary);
        // transform: rotateY(0deg);
        
        &-top{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 35%;
            border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
            
            font-size: 3.2rem;
            color: var(--color-secondary);
            background: rgba($color: #000000, $alpha: .25);
            background-blend-mode: multiply;
            
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
    }
    
    &__front-bottom{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        
        &-list{
            color: var(--color-primary);
            font-size: 3.5rem;
            font-weight: 600;
            list-style: none;
        }
    }
    &__back{
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, var(--color-card-gradient-1), var(--color-card-gradient-2));
        color: var(--color-secondary);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        
        & h1{
            position: absolute;
            top: 20rem;
            font-size: 5rem;
        }
        
        &::before{
            content: "";
            width: 60%;
            height: 35%;
            position: absolute;
            background-image:url(../img/bg-svg.png);
            background-size: cover;
            top: 1.5rem;
            left: 1.5rem;
        }
    }
    
    figure{
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: none;
        position: absolute;
        
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
        
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
}

.card-1{
    &__front{
        &-top{
            background-image: url("../img/card-1-photo.jpg");
            clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
            background-size: cover;
        }
    }
}
.card-2{
    &__front{
        &-top{
            background-image: url("../img/card-2-photo.jpg");
            clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
            background-size: cover;
        }
    }
}
.card-3{
    &__front{
        &-top{
            background-image: url("../img/card-3-photo.jpg");
            clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
            background-size: cover;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so bad, are you sure it needs to be fixed?

If this works using a `hover`, you can try setting the text to `display:hidden;` on hover - or whatever the event is.

Comment: Thank you! You gave me an idea. I used javascript to apply a class with visibility: hidden to the list. That way I can use the transition property to delay the disappearance until the user flips the card completely.

Thank you so much good sir!

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed.

I used javascript to apply a class with --visibility: hidden-- [EDIT: ended up using display: none because of interaction issues] to the list element. --That way I can use the transition property to delay the disappearance of the element until the user flips the card completely.-- [EDIT: It was a good idea at the beginning haha]